# Only show failures in `jest --watch`?

Tags: jestjs

I have Jest running in a Docker Container which runs during development. It outputs something like this every time a single file changes:

```
frontend_test_1       |  PASS  src/redux/someFile.test.js
frontend_test_1       |  PASS  src/components/MyComponent.test.js
frontend_test_1       |  PASS  src/components/AnotherComponent.test.js
frontend_test_1       |
frontend_test_1       | Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
frontend_test_1       | Tests:       5 passed, 5 total
frontend_test_1       | Snapshots:   0 total
frontend_test_1       | Time:        1.989 s, estimated 2 s
frontend_test_1       | Ran all test suites related to changed files.
frontend_test_1       |
```

As I add files, the list grows and it becomes unwieldy.

I really only care if tests fail. **Is it possible to only log failures?**